# 2000 Ford Excursion 5.4L 2wd

Tags: ford, ac, fan, cold

Reduced cold air flow from a/c

1. I replaced the fan
   2 replaced a/c resistor
2. Clean ac evaporative coil in behind fan.
3. Cleaned front evaporate coils in front of radiator Both with lye mix commercially available.
   Rinse and repeat. All coils clean.
4. New fan only had 2 speeds. So after reviewing U Tube I figured out they miss wired the moter so I reversed polarity ( switched the wires) and now have 4 speeds and more volume.

Issue is the temp and pressure.
Bought max ac @autozone and  used gauge it says way over pressure top of red zone.
So I bled off alot into a resealable r134a can down to top of green zone. Ac is now barely cold.
I added a 2oz oil and a smidgen (4 oz. ) 134a still barely cold like 68 to 70°
When i shut truck off it makes hissing sounds.

Last August I had vacume tested. Said was fine but claimed there was debris in lines from something deteriorating. Had it flushed and refilled.
Ran good last yr.

This all started when when to Yellowstone over 4th. On way home after 1k miles using ac. Switch and blower stopped working. As previously mentioned  replaced all parts and now it comes on but not cold enough.

Should I have it evacuated and recharged again .  Also.
When pulling the pressure off into my spare empty can there appears to be no liquid.  Only gas pressure.  So not sure what to do.

No codes  and clutch engages and lines get cold just not quite frozen cold. ???

Also the pressure of the autozone fan is less ( 40% ) than OEM fan. ?? But does work after reversing polarity.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: "When i shut truck off it makes hissing sounds." This is normal. I would not trust those charge cans for accurate reading, you need a AC manifold gauge set to diagnose it properly.